# significance of subscription in service call : Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-observable

I am a beginner to angular4 and trying to understand the concept of observable and subscription .

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    private subscription: Subscription 

    ngOnInit() {

      // case -1 -> service call 1 with subscription     

      this.subscription = this.service1.method1().subscribe(() => {});

     // case-2 -> service call 2 without subscription 

     this.service1.method2().subscribe(() => {});

    }
```

Now many times we don't need to use **this.subscription** (case-2), we can directly call the service by subscribing it.

My question is when should we use (in which scenario)  variable like

```
private subscription: Subscription;
```

Which is the best practice ?

Any help/blog/article will be appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: if you have `subscribe` its a good practice to have corresponding `unsubscribe` in components `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle hook. Its not always necessary, but its a good habit. and that's where your `subscription: Subscription` comes into play: it has `unsubscribe` method on it: `subscription:unsubscribe()`.

Comment: check my answer added all deatils might help you to understand it better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Subscription` type has a function called `unsubscribe`. You need to use `unsubscribe` to manually complete the observable ( *in most cases when it is infinite stream* ). If observable is not completed,  the stream of the observable will not be closed and memory leak will occur. You can write the unsubscription at the `ngOnDestroy` life cycle event and unsubscribe all observables at the component destroying.

What about HTTP requests, they are automatically completed after the response is returned, so you don't need to use `unsubscribe` with HTTP request.

You can also check **[When to Unsubscribe in Angular](https://netbasal.com/when-to-unsubscribe-in-angular-d61c6b21bad3)**.

Answer (score 0):

RxJs library is based on [**Observable pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) - In this pattern you keep watching for the source which either changing or generating new value for example. stock index where values of stock keep changing or keep sending new value.

So as per the Observable pattern

**Observable**  - is source which is keep sending value to your program which are going to listen and process it.

**Subscription** - is subscription to your observable which sends you value , and by subscription you indicate that you program is listing value which is coming from source , and in this event you also processing value which is coming in.

You can understand thing more clearly if you understand `Observable pattern`.

---

To answer you question `Subscription` this you need when you want to manage you subscript by yourself i.e. in you code.

with help of subscription token you can detach your code from observable , i.e. if you dont want to receive more value from observable i.e. source you should stop by using subscription by calling unsubscribe method.

Article : [Angular: Don't forget to unsubscribe()](http://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/) help you to understand token.

unsubscribe from source dont to avoid memory leaking.